# My Raspberry pi keep show msg : low voltage warning please check your power supply

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, supply

I have Raspberry pi 3 , and I am using  its power supply which give 5V -2.5 A , the problem is that the raspberry Pi keep show this message : **low voltage warning please check your power supply**

Comment: Your power supply or cable is not providing sufficient voltage. What it says on the label can be very different from what is actually seen on the board. This can be especially true if you are using a cheap charger or cable. If you have peripherals connected to the USB ports or GPIO pins I would also remove them (excluding a keyboard or mouse) to eliminate them as a cause of the problem.

Comment: if you go for a cheap power supply, consider getting one marked for double the amperage you need and be ready to add some capacitors.  they have a tendancy to mislabel using peak capability instead of continuous and skimp on capacitors.